# Logitech G hub lua script, trying to turn integer to string

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
--OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")

-- MP value: 34390, 31219
-- CC: 43405, 15670
-- OK: 36029, 36017

--if IsMouseButtonPressed(2) then
--  x, y = GetMousePosition()
--  OutputLogMessage("Mouse is at %d, %d\n", x, y)
--end

i = 61

while IsMouseButtonPressed(5) do
  MoveMouseTo(34390, 31219)
  Sleep(100)
  PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
  Sleep(100)
  PressAndReleaseKey("%d", i)
  i = i + 1
  OutputLogMessage(i)
  Sleep(100)
  PressAndReleaseKey(28)
  Sleep(100)
  MoveMouseTo(43405, 15670)
  PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
  Sleep(300)
end
```

I'm trying to convert an integer to a string. I've tried

```
PressAndReleaseKey(tostring(i))
```

But that didn't work.

I also tried

```
PressAndReleaseKey(i)
```

But that just turns it into a scancode which is "F3" btw.

What I'm trying to do is get it to click on something, type out "61", then increase the number by 1 each time it runs through the cycle.

Comment: `tostring()` is the correct way to turn an integer into a string, but beyond that I can't tell what you actually want. Can you add more context to your question? What do you want to happen and what's happening instead?

Comment: "61" is not a key. Do you want something like `PressAndReleaseKey("6"); PressAndReleaseKey("1")`? That would press 6, then 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
i = 0x61; -- hexadecimal!!!
PressAndReleaseKey(string.char(i))
```

That should probably do what you want.

---

Another approach is using function `PressAndReleaseHidKey()` - it has more consistent codes for keyboard keys: 4-29 are for letters `a-z`, 30-39 are for digits `1234567890`
For example, `PressAndReleaseHidKey(4)` is the same as `PressAndReleaseKey("a")`.

The complete list of arguments accepted by `PressAndReleaseHidKey`, `PressHidKey`, `ReleaseHidKey`:

| hidcode | description |
| --- | --- |
| 0x00 | Reserved (no event indicated) (not a physical key) |
| 0x01 | Keyboard ErrorRollOver (not a physical key) |
| 0x02 | Keyboard POSTFail (not a physical key) |
| 0x03 | Keyboard ErrorUndefined (not a physical key) |
| 0x04 | Keyboard a and A |
| 0x05 | Keyboard b and B |
| 0x06 | Keyboard c and C |
| 0x07 | Keyboard d and D |
| 0x08 | Keyboard e and E |
| 0x09 | Keyboard f and F |
| 0x0A | Keyboard g and G |
| 0x0B | Keyboard h and H |
| 0x0C | Keyboard i and I |
| 0x0D | Keyboard j and J |
| 0x0E | Keyboard k and K |
| 0x0F | Keyboard l and L |
| 0x10 | Keyboard m and M |
| 0x11 | Keyboard n and N |
| 0x12 | Keyboard o and O |
| 0x13 | Keyboard p and P |
| 0x14 | Keyboard q and Q |
| 0x15 | Keyboard r and R |
| 0x16 | Keyboard s and S |
| 0x17 | Keyboard t and T |
| 0x18 | Keyboard u and U |
| 0x19 | Keyboard v and V |
| 0x1A | Keyboard w and W |
| 0x1B | Keyboard x and X |
| 0x1C | Keyboard y and Y |
| 0x1D | Keyboard z and Z |
| 0x1E | Keyboard 1 and ! |
| 0x1F | Keyboard 2 and @ |
| 0x20 | Keyboard 3 and # |
| 0x21 | Keyboard 4 and $ |
| 0x22 | Keyboard 5 and % |
| 0x23 | Keyboard 6 and ^ |
| 0x24 | Keyboard 7 and & |
| 0x25 | Keyboard 8 and * |
| 0x26 | Keyboard 9 and ( |
| 0x27 | Keyboard 0 and ) |
| 0x28 | Keyboard Return (ENTER) |
| 0x29 | Keyboard ESCAPE |
| 0x2A | Keyboard Backspace |
| 0x2B | Keyboard Tab |
| 0x2C | Keyboard Spacebar |
| 0x2D | Keyboard - and _ |
| 0x2E | Keyboard = and + |
| 0x2F | Keyboard [ and { |
| 0x30 | Keyboard ] and } |
| 0x31 | Keyboard \ and |
| 0x32 | Keyboard Non-US # and ~ |
| 0x33 | Keyboard ; and : |
| 0x34 | Keyboard ' and " |
| 0x35 | Keyboard Grave Accent and Tilde |
| 0x36 | Keyboard , and < |
| 0x37 | Keyboard . and > |
| 0x38 | Keyboard / and ? |
| 0x39 | Keyboard Caps Lock |
| 0x3A | Keyboard F1 |
| 0x3B | Keyboard F2 |
| 0x3C | Keyboard F3 |
| 0x3D | Keyboard F4 |
| 0x3E | Keyboard F5 |
| 0x3F | Keyboard F6 |
| 0x40 | Keyboard F7 |
| 0x41 | Keyboard F8 |
| 0x42 | Keyboard F9 |
| 0x43 | Keyboard F10 |
| 0x44 | Keyboard F11 |
| 0x45 | Keyboard F12 |
| 0x46 | Keyboard PrintScreen |
| 0x47 | Keyboard Scroll Lock |
| 0x48 | Keyboard Pause |
| 0x49 | Keyboard Insert |
| 0x4A | Keyboard Home |
| 0x4B | Keyboard PageUp |
| 0x4C | Keyboard Delete |
| 0x4D | Keyboard End |
| 0x4E | Keyboard PageDown |
| 0x4F | Keyboard RightArrow |
| 0x50 | Keyboard LeftArrow |
| 0x51 | Keyboard DownArrow |
| 0x52 | Keyboard UpArrow |
| 0x53 | Keypad Num Lock and Clear |
| 0x54 | Keypad / |
| 0x55 | Keypad * |
| 0x56 | Keypad - |
| 0x57 | Keypad + |
| 0x58 | Keypad ENTER |
| 0x59 | Keypad 1 and End |
| 0x5A | Keypad 2 and Down Arrow |
| 0x5B | Keypad 3 and PageDn |
| 0x5C | Keypad 4 and Left Arrow |
| 0x5D | Keypad 5 |
| 0x5E | Keypad 6 and Right Arrow |
| 0x5F | Keypad 7 and Home |
| 0x60 | Keypad 8 and Up Arrow |
| 0x61 | Keypad 9 and PageUp |
| 0x62 | Keypad 0 and Insert |
| 0x63 | Keypad . and Delete |
| 0x64 | Keyboard Non-US `\` and `|` |
| 0x65 | Keyboard Application (context menu key) |
| 0x66 | Keyboard Power (not a physical key) |
| 0x67 | Keypad = |
| 0x68 | Keyboard F13 |
| 0x69 | Keyboard F14 |
| 0x6A | Keyboard F15 |
| 0x6B | Keyboard F16 |
| 0x6C | Keyboard F17 |
| 0x6D | Keyboard F18 |
| 0x6E | Keyboard F19 |
| 0x6F | Keyboard F20 |
| 0x70 | Keyboard F21 |
| 0x71 | Keyboard F22 |
| 0x72 | Keyboard F23 |
| 0x73 | Keyboard F24 |
| 0x74 | Keyboard Execute |
| 0x75 | Keyboard Help |
| 0x76 | Keyboard Menu |
| 0x77 | Keyboard Select |
| 0x78 | Keyboard Stop |
| 0x79 | Keyboard Again |
| 0x7A | Keyboard Undo |
| 0x7B | Keyboard Cut |
| 0x7C | Keyboard Copy |
| 0x7D | Keyboard Paste |
| 0x7E | Keyboard Find |
| 0x7F | Keyboard Mute |
| 0x80 | Keyboard Volume Up |
| 0x81 | Keyboard Volume Down |
| 0x82 | Keyboard Locking Caps Lock |
| 0x83 | Keyboard Locking Num Lock |
| 0x84 | Keyboard Locking Scroll Lock |
| 0x85 | Keypad Comma (Brazilian ".") |
| 0x86 | Keypad Equal Sign (on AS/400 keyboard) |
| 0x87 | Keyboard International1 (Brazilian "/" and "?", Kanji) |
| 0x88 | Keyboard International2 |
| 0x89 | Keyboard International3 |
| 0x8A | Keyboard International4 |
| 0x8B | Keyboard International5 |
| 0x8C | Keyboard International6 |
| 0x8D | Keyboard International7 (Double-byte/Single-byte) |
| 0x8E | Keyboard International8 |
| 0x8F | Keyboard International9 |
| 0x90 | Keyboard LANG1 (Hangul/English, Korean) |
| 0x91 | Keyboard LANG2 (Hanja, Korean) |
| 0x92 | Keyboard LANG3 (Katakana, Japanese) |
| 0x93 | Keyboard LANG4 (Hiragana, Japanese) |
| 0x94 | Keyboard LANG5 (Zenkaku/Hankaku, Japanese) |
| 0x95 | Keyboard LANG6 |
| 0x96 | Keyboard LANG7 |
| 0x97 | Keyboard LANG8 |
| 0x98 | Keyboard LANG9 |
| 0x99 | Keyboard Alternate Erase |
| 0x9A | Keyboard SysReq/Attention |
| 0x9B | Keyboard Cancel |
| 0x9C | Keyboard Clear |
| 0x9D | Keyboard Prior |
| 0x9E | Keyboard Return |
| 0x9F | Keyboard Separator |
| 0xA0 | Keyboard Out |
| 0xA1 | Keyboard Oper |
| 0xA2 | Keyboard Clear/Again |
| 0xA3 | Keyboard CrSel/Props |
| 0xA4 | Keyboard ExSel |
| 0xA5 | (Reserved) |
| 0xA6 | (Reserved) |
| 0xA7 | (Reserved) |
| 0xA8 | (Reserved) |
| 0xA9 | (Reserved) |
| 0xAA | (Reserved) |
| 0xAB | (Reserved) |
| 0xAC | (Reserved) |
| 0xAD | (Reserved) |
| 0xAE | (Reserved) |
| 0xAF | (Reserved) |
| 0xB0 | Keypad 00 |
| 0xB1 | Keypad 000 |
| 0xB2 | Thousands separator (locale-dependent symbol) |
| 0xB3 | Decimal Separator (locale-dependent symbol) |
| 0xB4 | Currency Unit (locale-dependent symbol) |
| 0xB5 | Currency Sub-unit (locale-dependent symbol) |
| 0xB6 | Keypad ( |
| 0xB7 | Keypad ) |
| 0xB8 | Keypad { |
| 0xB9 | Keypad } |
| 0xBA | Keypad Tab |
| 0xBB | Keypad Backspace |
| 0xBC | Keypad A |
| 0xBD | Keypad B |
| 0xBE | Keypad C |
| 0xBF | Keypad D |
| 0xC0 | Keypad E |
| 0xC1 | Keypad F |
| 0xC2 | Keypad XOR |
| 0xC3 | Keypad ^ |
| 0xC4 | Keypad % |
| 0xC5 | Keypad < |
| 0xC6 | Keypad > |
| 0xC7 | Keypad & |
| 0xC8 | Keypad && |
| 0xC9 | Keypad |
| 0xCA | Keypad |
| 0xCB | Keypad : |
| 0xCC | Keypad # |
| 0xCD | Keypad Space |
| 0xCE | Keypad @ |
| 0xCF | Keypad ! |
| 0xD0 | Keypad Memory Store |
| 0xD1 | Keypad Memory Recall |
| 0xD2 | Keypad Memory Clear |
| 0xD3 | Keypad Memory Add |
| 0xD4 | Keypad Memory Subtract |
| 0xD5 | Keypad Memory Multiply |
| 0xD6 | Keypad Memory Divide |
| 0xD7 | Keypad +/- |
| 0xD8 | Keypad Clear |
| 0xD9 | Keypad Clear Entry |
| 0xDA | Keypad Binary |
| 0xDB | Keypad Octal |
| 0xDC | Keypad Decimal |
| 0xDD | Keypad Dexadecimal |
| 0xDE | (Reserved) |
| 0xDF | (Reserved) |
| 0xE0 | Keyboard LeftControl |
| 0xE1 | Keyboard LeftShift |
| 0xE2 | Keyboard LeftAlt |
| 0xE3 | Keyboard Left GUI (Left Win) |
| 0xE4 | Keyboard RightControl |
| 0xE5 | Keyboard RightShift |
| 0xE6 | Keyboard RightAlt |
| 0xE7 | Keyboard Right GUI (Right Win) |

---

If you want to type "61":

```
i = 61
for key in tostring(i):gmatch"%d" do
   PressAndReleaseKey(key)
   Sleep(100)
end
```

Comment: I've tried what you put in the codeblock there @EgorSkriptunoff , I put a little more explanation on what I'm trying to do if that helps at all.

Comment: @xEternal - Answer updated.